# Cocoa Touch - Parsing Spread Sheets?

Tags: cocoa-touch, spread

Im working on some google doc spread sheets and I thought im not sure if cocoa can parsing the spread sheet data so I dont wanna do all this and find out its useless..

if it can be parsed what format should it be in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["Comma Separated Values"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Answer (score 1):

As said above, you can export the spreadsheet into a Comma separated table or a tab separated table and write some code to parse it. You can use NSScanner to parse them rather easily.